# MVC3 Pressing Enter in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a website,i have a view in my website for registration, and on pressing the signup button i am hitting an ActionMethod,every thing is working fine the problem is when after successful registration if user presses Enter on URL it is showing The resource cannot be found, how can i handle this?
Below is my controller code ==>

```
 public ActionResult Join(SignUpModel model)
        {        
                int create = Repository1.Create(UserEntity);
                if (create > 0)//if <= 0 means username already exists
                {
                    int savesetup = Repository2.SaveInfo(model);                                        
                    TempData["SucessMsg"] = "User registered Successfully";
                    return View("Index");
                }
                if (create < 0)
                {
                    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Username already exists";
                    return View("Index", model);
                }         

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "SignUp");
        }
```

and the View of Signup is Index View

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {         
            return View();
        }
```

Since i dont have View named Join,instead i am redirecting it to index page but when User is on Signup/Join URL and presses enter it shows The resource cannot be found

Comment: What url is displayed when people are pressing Enter and getting the error message? Could you post more of the error (like what resource isn't found) maybe?

Comment: are your routes configured properly..? make sure you havent added a route by mistake that takes in Index/SignUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `ActionResult Join(SignUpModel model)` marked with a [HttpPost]-attribute? If so, then it will only be invoked if the user makes a POST-request (and entering the url themselves will do a GET-request. If this is the case, simply add another action method called Join() without the [HttpPost]-attribute and use that to redirect them to the correct page (or display any information you want of course).

### Edit

I was a little hasty when reading your question and missed that you already redirected the user away from `ActionResult Join(SignUpModel model)`, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there is a View named Index.

```
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "SignUp");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {         
        return View();
    }
```

The above code is correct if there is a View named Index.return View() will search for a View with the same name of ActionResult in MVC. Make sure there is a View named Index. If there is not a view named index, it will give an Error Page like page not found.

Comment: Yes, my View name is Index.cshtml, When signup is successful it is showing message correctly on SameView(ie Index) but when i press enter on successful signup it is showing resource not found

Comment: Yes,I understand .Can you please tell me whats the current url when you are pressing enter button.